# nth child. Target every 4th/5th, 9th/10th, 14th/15th element

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a little blog layout and I want every 4th and 5th, 10th and 11th, 14th and 15th, etc. post to have a different class.

So basically there'll be 3 regular posts, then 2 with this new class, 3 more regular, 2 with new class, etc.

`:nth-child` perplexes me, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you rendering out each blog post? If you're using a loop it should be straight forward..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector, you are selecting `5n - 1` and `5n` elements

```
$('ul').children(':nth-child(5n-1), :nth-child(5n)').append('text')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wkxtL/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with pure css:

```
ul li:nth-child(5n),ul li:nth-child(5n-1){
   color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul>
     <li>List elements</li>
 </ul>
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wkxtL/2/

EDIT: Sorry, didn't read the question. This doesn't change teir class, just their apperence